# Mod_pagespeed is enabled. FileCachePath must not be empty:

Tags: apache2, vhosts, mod-pagespeed, webfaction

I've tried to restrain myself from asking too many questions on Stack Overflow, but I have been trying to get mod_pagespeed enabled on my Apache2 server for a couple days now, and am ready to start pulling out my hair hah. I installed mod_pagespeed, and mod_pagespeed_ap24, although I only need mod_pagespeed_ap24 for my version of Apache2. I edited Apache's configuration in /apache2/conf/httpd.conf loading the module in

```
LoadModule pagespeed_module  modules/mod_pagespeed_ap24.so
```

I restarted the server successfully, but get a 502 bad gateway, and this error

```
[mod_pagespeed 1.12.34.2-0 @27107] mod_pagespeed is enabled. FileCachePath must not be empty: define_name=(null) defne_line_number=0 server_hostname=web551.webfaction.com port=0
```

I tried multiple times to edit mod_pagespeed's config file in linux, but nothing worked. So instead I created a symbolic link to a static/php/cgi on Webfaction to serve my media  through an Apache server instead of their nginix server, so I could use an .htaccess file to configure my Apache server. I am still getting the issue however.

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"

</IfModule>



#Begin gzip and deflate
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/plain text/xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_pagespeed_ap24.c>
    ModPagespeed on
    ModPagespeedFileCachePath "/home/doc4design/var/cache/mod_pagespeed"
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,combine_css
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
</IfModule>
```

**Apache httpd.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/home/doc4design/webapps/django_2016/apache2"

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module      modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule pagespeed_module  modules/mod_pagespeed_ap24.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/doc4design/logs/user/access_django_2016.log combined
ErrorLog /home/doc4design/logs/user/error_django_2016.log

Listen 30651
KeepAlive Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxRequestWorkers 5
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 3
ThreadsPerChild 5

WSGIDaemonProcess django_2016 processes=2 threads=12 maximum-requests=100 python-path=/home/doc4design/webapps/django_2016:/home/doc4design/webapps/django_2016/doc4_2016:/home/doc4design/webapps/django_2$
WSGIProcessGroup django_2016
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/doc4design/webapps/django_2016/doc4_2016/webapp/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Did you install via `deb` or source? When I deployed `Mod_Pagespeed` I installed the `deb` and used `sudo a2enmod pagespeed`. Mod pagespeed automatically puts a conf file into `mods-available` so an easy `a2enmod` was possible for me.
A quick question, does the file path exist (the folder itself) for your `FileCachePath` parameter?

Comment: You might also have better luck asking on https://serverfault.com rather than here - strictly speaking this isn't a programming related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the path `/home/doc4design/var/cache/mod_pagespeed` exists? If so can Apache access the path?

Confirm the path exists and grant permissions to `www-data` on it, or which ever user apache is running under.

Comment: Hey Fraser, that ended up being the issue. I had apache .htaccess files trying to set the FileCachePath, but it was trying to configure the wrong server. My hosting provider, Webfaction, uses their own Nginix, and Apache2.4 servers for serving apps, media, and static assets. By directly setting the path inside my httpd.conf file inside my Apache2 directory, it fixed the issue.